# How to enable mode rewrite in apache2

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I have installed Apache2, PHP5, MySQL. And now I am trying to run my project, but getting error:

> The requested URL /toothi/home was not found on this server.
>   Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.2.169 Port 80

I am trying to run my project on **Ubuntu 12.04**

Comment: Please share your server configuration and folder structure.

Comment: does your application need Virtual host, if yes, did you configure it ?

Comment: I don't believe that mod_rewrite has anything to do with your case. Indeed, as @OlcayErtaş mentioned, please share your folder structure with us. IMHO I tend to believe that you're trying to access some wrong dir.

Comment: Are you sure you have file on the location which you're trying to access?

Comment: my configure apps/websites are in folder /var/www. using ubuntu 12.04. installed php5,apache & mysql

Answer (score 1):

To enable mod_rewrite in apache2-

> sudo a2enmod rewrite
>
> sudo apache2 restart

To use mod_rewrite from within .htaccess files (which is a very common use case), edit the default VirtualHost.

sudo vim /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

Below “DocumentRoot /var/www/” add the following lines:

```
<Directory “/var/www/”>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Restart the server again:

> sudo service apache2 restart